# PHP parse PMML-3_2 with SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, xpath

for testing xpath functionality i use valid PMMLv3.2 .xml file.

code:

```
$wtf = new SimpleXMLElement( file_get_contents( $_FILES['xml']['tmp_name'] ) );
$wtf->registerXPathNamespace('x', 'http://www.dmg.org/PMML-3_2');
echo '<pre>';var_dump($wtf->xpath('//x:Header'));
```

output:

```
array(1) {
   [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#18 (3) {
      ["@attributes"] => array(1) {
         ["copyright"] => string(54) "Copyright(c) SPSS Inc. 1989-2008. All rights reserved."
      }
      ["Application"] => object(SimpleXMLElement)#19 (1) {
         ["@attributes"] => array(2) {
            ["name"] => string(20) "SPSS Statistics 17.0"
            ["version"] => string(6) "17.0.0"
         }
      }
      ["Timestamp"] => object(SimpleXMLElement)#20 (0) {}
   }
}
```

But why then querying like this **$wtf->xpath('//x:Header/Application')** returns empty array? Empty array returns on any not root node.

Please, can somebody explain what i am doing wrong?

Comment: why this happens? just small typo took 4 hours :/
$wtf->xpath('//x:Header/x:_Appliaction_');
should be Application

Comment: So this (question) was just a typo problem and you solved it, right?